# NoSuchConversationException Spring Web Flow

Tags: spring, jsf-2.2, spring-webflow-2

After implementing the **Custom Conversation Manager** in the spring web flow using this post and post url is http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/web-flow/119955-spring-webflow-2-working-with-persistent-conversation-data.The values are persisting in the database successfully.

Now issue is that when user explicitly logging out from the application, logout screen display, but the **URI still containing the expired, ended and invalidated conversation Id** and when user again try to log in the same window, he/she getting NoSuchConversationException exception(see below code).

**Class where I am getting Exception:**

```
 public class PersistentConversationManager implements ConversationManager, Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
PersistentConversationHelper persistentConversationHelper;


public Conversation beginConversation(ConversationParameters conversationParameters)
        throws ConversationException {

    ConversationId convId = new SimpleConversationId(UUID.randomUUID());
    persistentConversationHelper.createConversation(new PersistentConversation(convId, conversationParameters.getName()));

    return getConversation(convId);
}

public Conversation getConversation(ConversationId id) throws ConversationException {
    if (PersistentConversationHolder.holdsConversation(id)) {
        // we already loaded the conversation for the calling thread
        return PersistentConversationHolder.getConversation(id);
    }
    else {
        // load the conversation
        com.csc.cscip.ux.model.WebFlowConversation webFlowConversation = persistentConversationHelper.readConversation(id);
        **if (webFlowConversation == null) {                
            throw new NoSuchConversationException(id);
        }**

        PersistentConversation conversation = new PersistentConversation(webFlowConversation);

        // cache it for the calling thread
        PersistentConversationHolder.putConversation(conversation);
        return conversation;            
    }
}
```

**Exception in log trace:**

```
2014-09-10 13:17:33,318 [http-bio-9090-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.webflow.scope.RequestScope  - Returning scoped instance 'httpServletResponse'
2014-09-10 13:17:33,999 [http-bio-9090-exec-9] ERROR com.csc.cscip.ux.common.webflow.persistance.PersistentConversationManager  - [ exception code < 2MFC3 > thrown < getConversation > exception message No conversation could be found with id '5e06bded-e3e4-42a5-8f70-f69c59f42ba6'
```

-- perhaps this conversation has ended?  with params 5e06bded-e3e4-42a5-8f70-f69c59f42ba6, ]
`org.springframework.webflow.conversation.NoSuchConversationException: No conversation could be found with id '5e06bded-e3e4-42a5-8f70-f69c59f42ba6'` -- perhaps this conversation has ended?

Currently I am trying to restart the flow when I am getting NoSuchConversationException exception but not able to succeed :(

Now how can i handle this issue/scenario?